# How split a string by equial parts?

Tags: objective-c, split, nsstring

How I can split a string into equal parts and not a character, ie, a string that is 20 characters divided into 5 strings with 2 characters each no matter what kind of character is?

don't work to me [NSString componentsSeparatedByString]: because the characters change randomly.

i'm using objetive-c on xcode 5

Comment: So `5 * 2 = 20` nowadays? as to the problem: have a look at `substringWithRange:`.

Comment: A simple loop and `substringWithRange:` ? It becomes interesting only in the case of "composed character sequences" like UTF-16 surrogate pairs (don't cut an Emoji in half :)

Comment: The exact way you would go about this differs depending on what EXACTLY you want to do, do you want to split every string into chunks of 5 characters, are all the strings you want to split a fixed length?

Comment: jajaj yes i'm sorry,I wrote fast and did not realize that was misspelled on 5 * 2 ​​= jajaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just an example of what you're probably looking to do. This method assumes the length of the string is evenly divisible by the intended substring length, so having a test string with 20 characters and a substring length of 2, will produce an array with 10 substrings with 2 characters in each. ***If the test string is 21 characters the 21st char will be ignored***. Once again, this is not THE way to do exactly what you want to do (which still isn't totally clear), but it is merely a demonstration of something similar to what you may want to be doing:

```
// create our test substring (20 chars long)
NSString *testString = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstu";

// our starting point will begin at 0
NSInteger startingPoint = 0;

// each substring will be 2 characters long
NSInteger substringLength = 2;

// create our empty mutable array
NSMutableArray *substringArray = [NSMutableArray array];

// loop through the array as many times as the substring length fits into the test
// string
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < testString.length / substringLength; i++) {
    // get the substring of the test string starting at the starting point, with the intended substring length
    NSString *substring = [testString substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(startingPoint, substringLength)];

    // add it to the array
    [substringArray addObject:substring];

    // increment the starting point by the amount of the substring length, so next iteration we
    // will start after the last character we left off at
    startingPoint += substringLength;
}
```

The above produced this:

> 2014-08-23 15:33:41.662 NewTesting[49723:60b] (
>       ab,
>       cd,
>       ef,
>       gh,
>       ij,
>       kl,
>       mn,
>       op,
>       qr,
>       st )